# What does "sich heftig wert" mean?

Tags: translation

I was reading [this article](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/ard-brennpunkt-und-hart-aber-fair-zum-rueckzug-von-akk-16628002.html?printPagedArticle=true#pageIndex_2) on FAZ, and came across this strange fragment:

> Wogegen sich Röttgen heftig wert: Die Werteunion sei nicht hilfreich.

Surely there is a typo there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there is an h missing. It should be "wehrt" (see dictionary "[sich] wehren").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a spelling mistake

Comment: Maybe not a bad idea to call these self-appointed defenders of christian-occidental values *Wehrteunion* ;)

Comment: @Iris could also be an intentional word-play. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Was spricht denn dafür? Macht der Autor das öfter? Ich habe nur den einen Absatz gelesen und dabei nicht den Eindruck gewonnen, ein solches Wortspiel, das auch keinen Sinn macht, weil sich Röttgen ja gegen die Werteunion wehrt, nicht mit dieser gegen etwas anderes.

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe nichtmal darauf geachtet, wer der Autor ist. Die FAZ ist allerdings ein Medium, welches sich an Leser gehobeneren Bildungsniveaus richtet, und denen könnte ein Autor auch durchaus zutrauen, ein Wortspiel zu erkennen, ohne explizit **Achtung, Wortspiel** dazuschreiben. Aber ein Schreibfehler ist schon wahrscheinlicher, ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend ergänzt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Als einer dieser Leser gehobenen Bildungsniveaus erwarte ich dann aber auch eine Pointe, nicht ein albernes, banales "ich schreibs mal ohne h, weil es geht ja gerade um Werte". Aber der Streit wert mir jetzt doch zu lange, das ist er gar nicht wert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct spelling would be *Wogegen sich Röttgen heftig wehrt:*
*Sich wehren* means *to defend oneself* or *to resist against something*
This could either be a spelling mistake (a missing "h") as some commentors have already suggested (and is the more likely explanation), but given the fact that the discussion that article is about deals with "Wert(e)" (="value(s)"), it could also be an intentional word-play.

Comment: I disagree with the word-play assumption. At least some in-word parentheses would be required to appear intentional. I consider as more likely: A problem with speech recognition not detected by subsequent spelling-checker.

Comment: @guidot Es soll auch Schreiber geben, die nicht immer gleich mit dem ganzen Lattenzaun winken, wenn sie ein Wortspiel machen.